# Alter Search Results display

Tags: 7, search

Currently when I search for something it displays the title of the node and if there is a match a small excerpt from either the content short summary or a small excerpt from the paragraph bundle. If there is no match it displays nothing.

How can i change this so it displays content even if only the title match. How can i change this so it displays the date it was published as well.

The modules involved are paragraphs, solr, searchAPI, Display Suite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply add a new view mode for search results:

1. Go to admin/structure/types/manage/page/display (where "page" is your content type)
2. Expand the *Show Custom display settings* fieldset
3. Check *Search index*

[image: Search index view mode]

4. Click Save
5. Go to admin/structure/types/manage/page/display/search_index (where "page" is your content type)

My advice would be to use the [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds) module as well for extra fields and more options.

Comment: Can you elaborate on Display Suite? I have that enabled but i'm not sure how to make it work.

Comment: I just updated my answer with more details.

Comment: I followed the steps above and nothing seems to have changed from my search results page.

Comment: It would appear that you need the [Apachesolr View Modes](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_view_modes) module as well: "Enables view modes to be used to control the display of search results".

Comment: Display suite is a good solution. I had some difficulties at the beginning to configure it : layout must be selected to enable Display Suite functionality such as get search snippet field etc.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you're using Drupal 8. You'll want to modify the `search-result.html.twig` template. By default, I believe the code looks something like this:

```
{{ title_suffix }}
<p{{ content_attributes }}>{{ snippet }}</p>
```

You can modify it to display something like the node's body field summary:

```
{{ title_suffix }}
{% if result.node.body.0.summary %}
  <p{{ content_attributes }}>{{ summary|length > 200 ? summary|slice(0, 250) ~ '...' : summary }}</p>
  <div>{{ result.node.created }}</div>
{% else %}
  <p{{ content_attributes }}>{{ snippet }}</p>
  <div>{{ result.node.created }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

EDIT: formatting